# Indice indefinido

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente codigo muy sencillo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Enviar Correo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 <body class="container-fluid">
 <form class="container bg-light mt-2 rounded p-3" id="Formulario">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Para</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Para" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">CC</label>
    <input type="texts" class="form-control" name="CC" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Tema</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Tema" placeholder="Cabezera .....">
  </div>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
   Agregar Lista
 </button>
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Listado</h5>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
       <span>Inicio</span>
       <input type="date" class="form-control" name="inicio" id="inicio">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
       <span>Fin</span>
       <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="fin" id="fin">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row mt-2">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
       <button type="button" name="button" id="search" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Buscar</button>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="table-responsive border p-3 rounded mt-2" id="listado">
     </div>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="Contenido" rows="3" placeholder=".........."></textarea>
  </div>
 <!--<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Enviar Correo">-->
   <button id="btnmrda" type="button" class="btn btn-info" >Enviar Correo</button>
</form>
 <div id="styleSelector">
 </div>
 </div>
  <div id="styleSelector">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="" id="Imprimir">

  </div>
  <div class='outer_div'></div><!-- Carga los datos ajax -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function MensajeS(Cabezera, Emisor, Mensaje,Receptor){
   $.ajax({
    url: 'EnviarCorreo.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: { Cabezera : Cabezera , Emisor : Emisor, Mensaje : Mensaje, Receptor : Receptor },
    beforeSend: function(){},
    success: function(data) {
     if(data=="Enviado"){
      alert("Se envio correctamente")
      $("#div").html(data);
     }else{
      alert("Error");
      $("#div").html(data);
     }
    }
   });
  }
  /*function calcular(h,m) {
   ahora = new Date();
   luego = new Date();
   luego.setHours(h);
   luego.setMinutes(m);
   luego.setSeconds(0);
   return luego.getTime() - ahora.getTime();
  }

  function abrir() {
   var Cabezera = "Hola Mundo";
   var Mensaje = "Buenos Dias";
   var Receptor = "Kenethrmc@gmail.com";
   var Emisor = "YO";
   MensajeS(Cabezera, Emisor, Mensaje, Receptor);
  }

  setTimeout('abrir()',calcular(14,41));*/
  function load(page){
   var ini = $("#inicio").val();
   var fin = $("#fin").val();
    $.ajax({
      url:'listasolicitud.php?action=ajax&page='+page+'&inicio='+ini+'&final='+fin,
      success:function(data){
        $("#listado").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
     }});
  }
  $("#search").click(function(){
    var ini = $("#inicio").val();
    var fin = $("#fin").val();
    if(ini.length>0 & fin.length>0){
     load(1);
    }
  });
  $(document).ready(function(e){
   load(1);

    $("#btnmrda").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    alert($("#Formulario").serialize());
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'email2.php',
            data: $("#Formulario").serialize(),
            success: function(){
              window.open('email2.php','_blank' );
            }
        });
    });
  });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

y en php email2.php

```
$FecIni=$_POST['inicio'];
$FecFin=$_POST['fin'];
if (isset($_POST['inicio'])){
   echo "hola";
}else{
   echo "in-hola";
 }
```

me sale

> Notice: Undefined index: inicio in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\email2.php on line 6

pero si se fijan si tengo el input 
 con el name inicio y fin

es algo sencillo pero me esta volviendo loco  @_@ porfavor ayudenme..gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

intenta pasandolo directamente como objeto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Enviar Correo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="container-fluid">
<form class="container bg-light mt-2 rounded p-3" id="Formulario">
  <div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Para</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Para" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">CC</label>
<input type="texts" class="form-control" name="CC" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Tema</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Tema" placeholder="Cabezera .....">
  </div>
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Agregar Lista
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Listado</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
      <span>Inicio</span>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="inicio" id="inicio">
     </div>
     <div class="col">
      <span>Fin</span>
      <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="fin" id="fin">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-2">
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <button type="button" name="button" id="search" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Buscar</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive border p-3 rounded mt-2" id="listado">
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="Contenido" rows="3" placeholder=".........."></textarea>
  </div>
<!--<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Enviar Correo">-->
  <button id="btnmrda" type="button" class="btn btn-info" >Enviar Correo</button>
</form>
<div id="styleSelector">
</div>
</div>
 <div id="styleSelector">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="" id="Imprimir">

 </div>
 <div class='outer_div'></div><!-- Carga los datos ajax -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function MensajeS(Cabezera, Emisor, Mensaje,Receptor){
  $.ajax({
   url: 'EnviarCorreo.php',
   type: "POST",
   data: { Cabezera : Cabezera , Emisor : Emisor, Mensaje : Mensaje, Receptor : Receptor },
   beforeSend: function(){},
   success: function(data) {
    if(data=="Enviado"){
     alert("Se envio correctamente")
     $("#div").html(data);
    }else{
     alert("Error");
     $("#div").html(data);
    }
   }
  });
 }
 /*function calcular(h,m) {
  ahora = new Date();
  luego = new Date();
  luego.setHours(h);
  luego.setMinutes(m);
  luego.setSeconds(0);
  return luego.getTime() - ahora.getTime();
 }

 function abrir() {
  var Cabezera = "Hola Mundo";
  var Mensaje = "Buenos Dias";
  var Receptor = "Kenethrmc@gmail.com";
  var Emisor = "YO";
  MensajeS(Cabezera, Emisor, Mensaje, Receptor);
 }

 setTimeout('abrir()',calcular(14,41));*/
 function load(page){
  let data = { "page":page, "inicio": $("#inicio").val(),"fin": $("#fin").val()};
   $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
     url:'listasolicitud.php',
     data: data,
     success:function(data){
       $("#listado").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    }});
 }
 $("#search").click(function(){
   var ini = $("#inicio").val();
   var fin = $("#fin").val();
   if(ini.length>0 & fin.length>0){
    load(1);
   }
 });
 $(document).ready(function(e){
  load(1);

   $("#btnmrda").on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault(e);
   alert($("#Formulario").serialize());
    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'email2.php',
           data: $("#Formulario").serialize(),
           success: function(){
             window.open('email2.php','_blank' );
           }
       });
   });
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: como seria como objeto? no logro ver alguna modificacion en mi codigo si es que la haz hecho.

Comment: revisa la `function load(page){` de mi ejemplo

Comment: si ya lo veo, pero como pongo la variable data junto con la URL , la necesito porque me carga una paginacion ...si la borro ya no sale

Comment: asi como estaba antes

Comment: data envia los parametros a la url: si le das url `example.php` esto enviara la `data` como objeto a esa url con formato `example.php?dato=1&dato2=2` y asi

Comment: haa, bueno pero no carga con la variable data que me pusiste ahi en la funcion :/ :(